# Attempting to load content into dialog (modal) via URL

Tags: javascript

I have a page that contains both static and dynamic content. On the static portion, I've attached a link that looks like this:

```
<p>
  <a id="trigger" class="use-ajax" data-dialog-options="{&quot;width&quot;:800}" data-dialog-type="modal"
      href="/profile/133">Profile
  </a>
</p>
```

Works flawlessly. The link is clicked and a modal(dialog) from Drupal core (powered by jQuery UI) is displayed.

However; in another portion of the page, I've inserted content into the DOM with code that looks like this:

```
$( ".insert" ).load(data + " .rlp-detail-more", loadComplete).attr("data-research-content", dataResearch);
```

That code contains EXACTLY the same string of html as above...

However, clicking the link takes me to the content with no overlay/modal/dialog.

And it gets weirder...

If I leave the inserted content open and click on the link further down in the static content, suddenly they both work... e.g., the jquery event hander somehow got attached to the inserted content.

My question is... How can I force an attachment of the event handler.

This question take a pretty good understanding of the jQuery dialog event and Drupal 8 integration of jQuery UI

[image]

Comment: This doesn't provide a solution, but it does provide insight as to why the behaviors are getting clobbered.
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview

Apparently .load should be avoided. "...If used properly this will ensure that your code runs both on normal page loads and when data is loaded by AJAX (or BigPipe!) - but not jQuery methods like load() which should be avoided as Drupal behaviors will fail to load for loading functions other than ajax()."

So what to do to replace .load?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is an elegant solution - but it is a workaround.  The issue seems to be that .load kills Drupal behaviors. So, after executing jQuery .load(), I ran $(Drupal.attachBehaviors()).

End of the problem - so far, no ill effect.  Still wondering if I can go about this without using .load.  Maybe .ajax()?

Comment: I had to wrap a .once() around the function that was calling the Drupal.attachBehaviors() or else, since my code was also in a behavior, it creates a loop. But even though this does work; the page load time is more than doubled. So not really a solution.

Comment: and sure enough.. 2 min after my last post saying this was too slow to work.. i figured it out. Instead of adding Drupal.attachBehaviors() after my replace code (I have a .replace function not .load; but suspect it's the same issue); i guessed at trying to "re-attach" only my behavior using: Drupal.attachBehaviors('my_behavior'). Works great now.